# Open Source .Net GIS software end-to-end

Tags: qgis, iis

I need to provide a client with an end-to-end web-based GIS solution running on IIS. I will admit to not knowing much about the subject, other than having developed a Google Earth enabled version of the project.

However, I need to develop a version that works offline, in the sense that I have an internal network without internet connection.

My problem is twofold:

1. I don't know what I need, or rather I don't know how many separate layers make up a GIS server. For instance, I thought QGIS Server by itself would be sufficient, but I still need to get my hands on a spatial data store (or do I?) and it seems that QGIS will only run on a Windows environment if IIS is disabled.
2. I don't know where to get my hands on the various components I don't know I need.

Has anyone implemented a .NET web-based GIS service utilizing Open Source technology?

UPDATE: The features I need are:

1. Javascript API
2. Ability to easily import custom tiles, e.g. for places like Angola that don't have low-level tiles
3. Ability to add and remove place markers with balloons(like google maps pins with info window popup) using javascrip API

Comment: What kind of features do you need?

Comment: I've edited the question to add requested features.

Comment: This might be helpful explaining the pieces you may or may not need: http://trac.tomliebert.com/wiki/eduWebMapAppStructure

Comment: Thanks man. It's indeed quite helpful. At least now I know what I need. Which handles 50% of the problem.